# Software I2C and VL6180

Tags: microcontroller, pic, i2c, light-sensor

Hell,
I'm trying to use the following sensor VL6180 with software I2C on PIC18F2458 running at 4Mhz, with USB functionality.
Currently the sensor doesn't work in terms of sending measurmenet, it can only be initialized at startup, but sometimes it couldn't do that also.

The max frequency from the software I2c library that MikroC provides is 20khz.
So my question would that sensor work with 20KHz.
https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Proximity/DM00112632.pdf Sensor Data sheet.

Comment: I2c is fairly forgiving. You have the correct pull ups and short wires?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it works fine. Datasheet does not specify any minimum frequency or timeouts.